# Show default message when listbox is empty (Windows Phone 8.1)

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

I want to display the default message when list box is empty and for same I used following code but this code is not working :

```
<HubSection x:Name="PivotFromAccount" Style="{StaticResource HubSectionStyle2}"  >
                <DataTemplate>

                    <Border Style="{StaticResource brdhubsectionstyle}">
                        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Style="{StaticResource GridMainStyleHubSession}">
                            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                            <Border Style="{StaticResource brdheaderstyle}">
                                <TextBlock Text="From Account" Style="{StaticResource lblheaderstyle}"  />
                            </Border>

                            <ListBox   x:Name="lstAccountDetailsfrom" Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding }" 
                                   Style="{StaticResource LstBoxStyleBranches}"  
                                   Tapped="lstAccountDetailsfrom_Tapped" 
                                   ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource lstAccountliststyle}"
                                 ItemTemplate="{StaticResource lstAccountlistDataTemplate}" >
                            </ListBox>

                            <TextBlock Margin="4" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" Text="List is empty" x:Name="txtmessage" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black"  />



                          <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                                <ic:DataTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding ElementName=lstAccountDetailsfrom, Path=Items.Count,Converter={StaticResource DataTriggerBehavior},Mode=TwoWay}" Value="0" ComparisonCondition="GreaterThan">
                                    <ic:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=txtmessage}" PropertyName="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                </ic:DataTriggerBehavior>
                            </i:Interaction.Behaviors>


                        </Grid>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </HubSection>
```

I tried with the Ivalue converter also like below but it is also not much more helpful.  It is always sending 0 count to ValueConverter

```
<TextBlock Margin="4" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" Text="List is empty" x:Name="txtmessage" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lstAccountDetailsfrom,Converter={StaticResource DataTriggerBehavior},Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your data source is an `ObservableCollection` you can bind to its `Count` property with a custom `IValueConverter` than converts `0` to `Visible` and `1` to `Collapsed` and use it on the `TextBlock`. No behavior needed.

Comment: I tried same but its not helpful its always show 0 count when I debug in Ivalue Converter following is my code

    '<TextBox Margin="4" FontStyle="Italic" FontSize="12" x:Name="txtmessage" Grid.Row="1" Foreground="Black" Text="Arjun Balip" IsReadOnly="True" Visibility="{Binding ElementName=lstAccountDetailsfrom,Path=Items.Count,Converter={StaticResource DataTriggerBehavior}}" />'

Comment: Do not bind the ListBox.Items.Count, bind the Count of your collection. I see you have ItemsSource="{Binding}" so use Visibility="{Binding Converter={StaticResource YourConverter}}